# What is the command to list the available avdnames

Tags: android, shell, configuration, adb, android-virtual-device

I know I can start the emulator avd by typing

```
emulator.exe @avdname
```

But is there a command to list the available avdnames?
Where are this avd configuration stored?

Comment: on windows ? C:\users\you\.android\avd\ so prolly on linux it will be ~/.android/avd/

Comment: for Mac command looks like  emulator @Name from list of avds

Answer (score 158, accepted):

AFAIK `avdmanager list avd` is what you need.

Comment: List all your emulators:

emulator -list-avds
Run one of the listed emulators:

emulator @name-of-your-emulator
where emulator is under:

${ANDROID_SDK}/tools/emulator

Comment: This answer is almost six years old, and while still technically valid, the **android** command has been deprecated in favor of **dkmanager** (and avdmanager).

Answer (score 207):

Using sdk/tools/emulator

This will list all available avds

```
emulator -list-avds
```

Answer (score 37):

get into Android/sdk/tools and run following command

```
./emulator -list-avds
```

which will return something like

```
Nexus_5X_API_P
Nexus_6_API_25
```

Comment: how is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37759064/1778421 ?

Answer (score 29):

List all your emulators:

> emulator -list-avds

Run one of the listed emulators:

> emulator @name-of-your-emulator

where emulator is under:

> ${ANDROID_SDK}/tools/emulator

Answer (score 21):

I try few combination and it worked :), it was pretty obvious

```
android list avd
```

the output is something like this

```
Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: EMULLL
    Path: /home/krste_ristevski/.android/avd/EMULLL.avd
  Target: Android 2.3.3 (API level 10)
    Skin: WVGA800
  Sdcard: 512M
```

now with

```
emulator @EMULLL
```

I can start the emulator from console

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone reading this, "android list avd" has been deprecated and will throw the following warning:

"""The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager"""

Answer (score 12):

This is an old post, but I am currently using this script to display the avd names and start one.

```
#! /bin/bash
# (@) start-android
# If the emulator command exists on this device, displays a list of emulators
# and prompts the user to start one

# Check if the emulator command exists first
if ! type emulator > /dev/null; then
  echo "emulator command not found"
  exit 1
fi

# Gather emulators that exist on this computer
DEVICES=( $(emulator -list-avds 2>&1 ) )

# Display list of emulators
echo "Available Emulators
----------------------------------------"
N=1
for DEVICE in ${DEVICES[@]}
do
  echo "$N) $DEVICE"
  let N=$N+1
done

# Request an emulator to start
read -p "
Choose an emulator: " num

# If the input is valid, launch our emulator on a separate PID and exit
if [ $num -lt $N ] && [ $num -gt 0 ];
then
  DEVICE=${DEVICES[$num-1]}
  emulator "@$DEVICE" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
  exit 0
else
  echo "Invalid Entry : $num"
  exit 1
fi
```

Here is an example run and output:

```
./start-android.sh
Available Emulators
----------------------------------------
1) Nexus_5X_API_23
2) Nexus_9_API_23

Choose an emulator: 1
```

Comment: an elegant solution. I always end out running the list command and then copy-pasting from the list. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

On Mac and Linux operating system:

1. Navigate to `Android/sdk/emulators`
2. Run command `./emulator -list-avds`

This will give you all the avd's created on your system.

Answer (score 3):

I have a simple method (Only for windows):

1. First of all set permanent path to adb in your system (Pretty similar like java). Find yours, For most of cases - `C:\Program Files\android\android-sdk\platform-tools` and copy it. Now go through your system properties and find Advance System Setting. Now find Environment Variable, in system variable tab find path. If there is no path then create a new variable and  name it Path and paste the copied value in next field. But if there is already a Path, then open it and put a `;` semi-colon at the last of value box and paste the copied value.
2. Now you are almost done.! Check it by typing `adb` in cmd
3. and now type `adb devices`, thats what you wanted. Cheers.!

Comment: This will show all connected android devices to your computer including avd too.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the emulator exe is installed and is present in the PATH env variable:

Windows:
`where emulator`

```
C:\Users\ShahidSiddiqui>where emulator
C:\Users\ShahidSiddiqui\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe
```

*nix/Mac:
`which emulator`

If no emulator found, either install it or fix the PATH to include its path.

You can check for the avd's present in your PC by running command:

```
PS C:\Users\ShahidSiddiqui> dir $HOME\.android\avd


    Directory: C:\Users\ShahidSiddiqui\.android\avd


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         7/05/2021   2:55 pm                Copy_of_HighRAM_Custom_API_30-Clone.avd
d-----        27/04/2021   5:36 pm                HighRAM_Custom_API_30.avd
d-----        29/01/2021  10:19 pm                Nexus_5X_API_30.avd
d-----        30/03/2021   1:27 pm                Nexus_5X_API_30_2.avd
d-----        22/01/2021   8:03 am                Pixel_4_API_30.avd
d-----        24/12/2020  10:14 am                Pixel_4_API_30_-2.avd
d-----        18/03/2021   2:55 pm                ShahidDevice_API_30.avd
-a----        29/04/2021  10:00 am            176 HighRAM_Custom_API_30-Clone.ini
-a----        29/01/2021   4:36 pm            148 HighRAM_Custom_API_30.ini
-a----        25/03/2021   4:20 pm            140 Nexus_5X_API_30_-New.ini
```

The INI files are the name of the AVDs that you can run.

If you have configured things properly, looking the AVDs is quite easy. Run command:

```
PS C:\Users\ShahidSiddiqui> emulator -list-avds
HighRAM_Custom_API_30-Clone
HighRAM_Custom_API_30
Nexus_5X_API_30_-New
```

To launch any of these avds, run the command (I am using which I am working on it):

```
PS C:\Users\ShahidSiddiqui\.android\avd> emulator -avd HighRAM_Custom_API_30-Clone
emulator: Android emulator version 30.5.5.0 (build_id 7285888) (CL:N/A)
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
added library vulkan-1.dll
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:301: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
```

And a sweet AVD will be launched.
Cheers!

NOTE: `adb devices` command will only list the currently running avds and real android devices. It will not show emulators (i.e. avds configured).

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users arriving here, you can find the previously mentioned **android/sdk/tools** directory at **/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/tools/**