# How to list the available Android Virtual Devices (AVDs)

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to follow [What is the command to list the available avdnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837952/what-is-the-command-to-list-the-available-avdnames), but I'm missing a bit of context. I gather that the command

```
android list avd
```

needs to be typed into a command-line interface (presumably the [Android Debug Bridge (adb)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html)), but how do I start up this interface? I've installed `adb` and but if I simply type it as a command at the command line, only a manual is printed.

**Update**

Following the answer given, I went to the `~/Android/Sdk/tools` (I used the default location during installation) and ran `./android list avd` (see below). (There are other errors, but at least the command works).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Move to the directory where you have installed **Android SDK**.
2. Move inside **Tools** folder and write command `android list avd`

Comment: I had to run `./android list avd` with a `./` in front.

Answer (score 2):

Info update, selected solution works but its deprecated, nowadays you should use:

cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools
./bin/avdmanager list avd